# NodeJs - Remove multiple numbers and dots from a text file

Tags: javascript, regex

I tried to remove numbers along with dots using nodejs

```js
const replace = "1."
const replacer = new RegExp(replace, 'g', '')

function removeText() {
    let originalText = '
1. I can own unlimited wealth on this earth
2. My potential for wealth knows no bounds
3. I attract limitless financial opportunities
    ';
    
    let newText = originalText.replace(replacer, '');

    console.log(newText);
}

removeText();
```

using this code I can only remove "1." but what about `2.`, `3.`, I have this counting upto 100, can someone help me?

Comment: Well, that's what regexes are for, but these are really basics you can get a grasp on by looking at some regex tutorials/sandboxes, i.e.: regexr, regex101, regexlearn.. or any guide materials really.

Comment: what does this have to do with `node.js`? this is just regular js

Comment: @ChrisG isn't this nodejs? I thought it was because it's running in console

Comment: @SamuelNovelinka I don't think you have answer to my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ChatGPT helped, To remove the line numbers (1., 2., and 3. Up to 100 and so on...) from the texts using only one function in Node.js, you can use the `replace()` function with a regular expression pattern. Here's an example:

```js
const text = `
1. Test.
2. Test.
3. Test.
`;

const modifiedText = text.replace(/^\d+\. /gm, '');

console.log(modifiedText);
```

Output:

```
Test.
Test.
Test.
```

In the above code, we use the `replace()` function with a regular expression `^\d+\.`  to match any line starting with one or more digits followed by a dot and a space. The `^` represents the start of the line, `\d+` matches one or more digits, `\.` matches the dot character, and the space after it matches a space character. The `g` flag is used for a global search, and the `m` flag is used for multiline matching.

By replacing the matched pattern with an empty string, we effectively remove the line numbers from the text. Have a nice day

Comment: Note that this will also remove such a sequence even if it's at the middle of string. Add a `^` before `[0-9]` and the `m` flag to anchor the whole expression to the start of each line and a `+` after `[0-9]` to match 1 or more digits; do remember to escape the dot as well: [`/^[0-9]+\./gm`](https://regex101.com/r/SOBw0Z/1).

Comment: I have updated my answer with a correct solution in it.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply achieve this by just using digit `RegEx`.

Live Demo **:**

```js
let originalText = `
1. I can own unlimited wealth on this earth
2. My potential for wealth knows no bounds
3. I attract limitless financial opportunities
`;

let newText = originalText.replace(/\d./g, '');

console.log(newText);
```

Answer (score 1):

split the string by lines. Filter out the empty values. Split each line by number followed by dot and finally join them back with new line.

```js
let originalText = `
1. I can own unlimited wealth on this earth
2. My potential for wealth knows no bounds
3. I attract limitless financial opportunities
    `;

originalText=originalText.split('\n').filter(l=>l).map(line=>line.split(/\d+\.\s/)[1]).join('\n')
```